# React bootstrap - no change in bundle size when importing components directly

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-bootstrap

Following the https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction#importing-components I've changed all imports in my project from `import * as rb from 'react-bootstrap'` to `import <component> from 'react-bootstrap/<component'`. I was expecting this would lead to a smaller bundle size, but after analysing via source-map-explorer the bundle size is pretty much the same (it even grew by unnoticeable amount). The project was created by create-react-app, **react** **v17.0.2** and **react-bootstrap** **v2.2.2**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create React App supports **tree shaking**, which is automatically configured. Tree shaking removes unused code from the packages: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_shaking.

This results in the same size, because in the end there is no difference between using only some components or using the whole package and stripping unused parts of it.